# Error while restoring oracle 10g .dmp file in oracle database 12c

Tags: oracle, import, restore, dump, oracle12c

I've got a .dmp file created with Oracle 10g containing the database of one of my clients. I can't for the life of me get it set up with my 12c installation. I can connect to my db using `https://localhost:5500/em`

I've created a user 'BOB' in my desired PDB and granted import, read and write permissions. Next I try to import using the following command:

`impdp BOB/password@//localhost:1521/pdbname full=y directory=dpdump_dir dumpfile=BOB.dmp`

However this gives me the following errors:

UDI-12541: operation generated ORACLE error 12541

ORA-12541: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

In the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora i have EZCONNECTOR and ports 1521. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Many thanks in advance,
Bob

Comment: get a dba involved in this to help with your job.

Comment: @ik_zelf I've managed to get a bit further, is this something I can fix myself or should I still contact a dba?

Comment: I don't think you need to add the server and port to the impdb command, only the SID. Try impdp BOB/password@pdbname full=y directory=dpdump_dir dumpfile=BOB.dmp

Comment: Given the questions you ask I would say, get a dba involved. dba's are used to setup infrastructures and perform backup recoveries. It would save you a lot of time.

Comment: You need to specify the correct service name to connect to the corresponding pdb. You can check for current services by querying the v$active_services view.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that you can do tnsping for pdbname to ensure db connect :- $ tnsping bdbname
If you get details of connection string by tnsping, you can try command with following format:
impdp bob/password@127.0.0.1:1521/pdbname directory=dpdump_dir dumpfile=BOB.dmp

I have removed "full=y" as it's not required if you are not restoring full database, specially it used apply with imp/exp utility.

You should remember that pdbname is being specified as a dbname/service_name in your example. You can confirm service_name by following command:
$ lsnrctl services; /* You can get service name and put it on your impdp command. */

In addition, you can try without specifying ip,port and dbname as you are working in localhost itself:
$ impdp bob/password directory=dpdump_dir dumpfile=BOB.dmp

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check the connection
sqlplus> BOB/password@localhost:1521/pdbname

If you cannot connect, please connect with sys / as sysdba
Then using command:
 SQL> alter session set container=pdbname
 SQL> alter pluggable database pdbname open

Then quit and try to your command again. :)